# JQuery Mobile dynamic page with listview after ChangePage

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, dynamic-data

I am stuck with my JQuery Mobile app trying to dynamically populate a listview  of a page. I got it up and running, but found out it only worked when I directly requested the page (eg. mydomain.com/page.html) when I linked to the page from another JQM page it only worked after using the refresh button in the browser.

This is my  JS code.

```
                $(function() {
                    var dirs=window.location.pathname.split('/'),
                    current_dir =dirs[dirs.length-2];
                    var vars = [], hash;
                    var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
                    if(q != undefined){
                        q = q.split('&');
                        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
                            hash = q[i].split('=');
                            vars.push(hash[1]);
                            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                        }
                    }
                                alert(current_dir);

                    $.getJSON("../json.php",{
                        section: current_dir,
                        id: vars['id'],
                        query: vars['q']
                    }, 
                    function(json){     
                                if (json.mededeling) {
                                $("#recent").append('<li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Mededelingen<span class="ui-li-count">'+json.mededeling.length+'</span></li>');
                                //loop through deals
                                $.each(json.mededeling,function(i,item){
                                    $("#recent").append('<li><a href="nieuws/='+item.id+
                                                        '" data-transition="slide">'+
                                                        '<h3>'+item.title +'</h3>'+
                                                        '<p>'+item.subtitle+'</p></a></li>');
                                 });
                                } 
                                if (json.nieuws) {
                                 $("#recent").append('<li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Nieuws<span class="ui-li-count">'+json.nieuws.length+'</span></li>');
                                //loop through deals
                                $.each(json.nieuws,function(i,item){
                                    $("#recent").append('<li><a href="news.html?'+item.id+
                                                        '" data-transition="slide">'+
                                                        '<h3>'+item.title +'</h3>'+
                                                        '<p>'+item.subtitle+'</p></a></li>');
                                 });
                                }
                                if (json.onderwijs) {
                                 $("#recent").append('<li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Onderwijs vandaag<span class="ui-li-count">'+json.onderwijs.length+'</span></li>');
                                //loop through deals
                                $.each(json.onderwijs,function(i,item){
                                    $("#recent").append('<li><a href="onderwijs/index.html?'+item.id+
                                                        '" data-transition="slide">'+
                                                        '<h3>'+item.title +'</h3>'+
                                                        '<p>'+item.speaker+'</p></a></li>');
                                 });
                                }
                                 $("#recent").listview('refresh');
                            });
                });
```

So I guessed it had something to do with the AJAX calls of JQM.

I searched extensively but now I am really lost.

Any help putting me back on trach is highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Hello, it is difficult to replicate this on jsfiddle (because of those multiple pages). Can you please add what is returned by the browser when you open /section_one/ ?

Comment: It outputs the page requested, but 'content' div remains empty.

Comment: I am quite puzzled because you said that it works when loaded using the URL. Mostly because the pagebeforechange handler is called not when the first page is loaded, but when you try to navigate out from that page. Is this the case?

Comment: Also try to navigate in the page before you start adding the contents. I am not saying that this is the solution, but it might help in terms of clarifying where may be the problem. Something like
$page = $(current_dir); $.mobile.changePage( $page, options ); and then the rest

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Previously (in old code) I found a way to insert data to a listview using the method in the first JS files (I updated my code above). This however did not work when I requested this page using a link in another JQM file. That's why I tried to use the pagebeforechange event.

Comment: Ok, considering your first attempt, can you try to use event called pageinit (http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) instead of $(function() .. )? Is it called when you navigate into the next page?

Comment: Something like: 
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    alert("Page initialized");
}

Comment: Ok. We are getting close... I reverted to my first attempt and added the `$(document).on('pageinit', function(){` instead of `$function(){`. Now the listview updates as needed when i load the page, but when I navigate to another page the listview doesn't update, unless I do a page refresh in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after changing the event listener in my first try to

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(){
```